# A tree that's making quiet "creaking" sounds, and stops when I tap it...insects?

Tags: entomology, trees

So I have a very dead tree (not a biologist, so this just means "no leaves when the trees around it do have leaves"), and I noticed when I stand close to it I can actually hear a "creaking" sound - I recorded a video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3ojwzje1ui6phh/PXL_20230514_235204506.mp4?dl=0

It's a little hard to hear, but I think it's distinct enough. Regular, consistent. And....when I tap the tree, it stops for a moment! (I do this at about 0:16 in the video.) And, if you wait long enough, it starts again! (This is around 1:13 in the video.)

I tried to shoot various parts of the tree - there is damage that I think is Woodpecker, and also some damage that looks like insects....could this be insects? I've read that dry conditions can cause a tree to creak, but not only is it not that dry here, but the tree is very dead!

Anyone have any idea what this sound is?

Comment: When our southern pines die; borers get into them quickly and are relatively loud  ( in a quiet forest). .Tapping the tree will stop them briefly.

Comment: @blacksmith37, ah and https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef437 says "the most obvious symptoms [...] These include [...] holes in the bark that exude sawdust or pitch", that might actually be what you see in the video.